# Chapel: Copying Stridable Domains

Tags: chapel

I want to store an array of domains. My code is similar to this:

```
var doms:[1..10] domain(1);
...
doms[i]={0..30 by 3}
```

I get the following error:

```
cannot assign from stridable domain to an unstridable domain without an an explicit cast
```

Using a cast `dom[i]={0..30 by 3} : domain(1)` I loose the stride information.
How can I copy domains without loosing the stride?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rectangular domain type like in the example shown actually has three parameters that define it: `rank`, `idxType`, and `stridable` (the example in the question specifies `rank=1`).  The `stridable` parameter is `false` by default, so cannot be assigned a stridable domain. To specify that the domain should be stridable, you can declare the domain type with `stridable=true`:

```
var doms: [1..10] domain(1, stridable=true);
...
doms[i] = {0..30 by 3};
```

As you discovered, casting the strided domain to the type `domain(1)` silently discarded the stride since a `domain(1)` can only have a unit stride.  If you would prefer to have an error instead of silently dropping the stride you can use a `safeCast` instead. A `safeCast` will verify that the original domain has unit stride before discarding it, and will issue an error if not:

```
doms[i] = {0..30 by 1}.safeCast(domain(1)); // This is allowed.
doms[i] = {0..30 by 3}.safeCast(domain(1)); // This is a runtime error.
```

Comment: Does setting stridable = true affect the performance if the stride happens to be 1?

Comment: Yes, `stridable=true` can impact performance even if the stride is 1.  The compiler is able to choose faster code paths if it knows that the stride will always be 1 (`stridable=false`) vs. if it doesn't know the stride (`stridable=true`).